# Schedule jobs between GPUs for PyTorch Models

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, scheduling

I'm trying to build up a system that trains deep models on requests. A user comes to my web site, clicks a button and a training process starts.

However, I have two GPUs and I'm not sure which is the best way to queue/handle jobs between the two GPUs: start a job when at least one GPU is available, queue the job if there are currently no GPUs available. I'd like to use one GPU per job request.

Is this something I can do in combination with Celery? I've used this in the past but I'm not sure how to handle this GPU related problem.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `celery` as I've never used it, but conceptually what seems reasonable (and the question is quite open ended anyway):

- create thread(s) responsible solely for distributing tasks to certain GPUs and receiving requests
- if any GPU is free assign task immediately to it
- if both are occupied estimate time it will probably take to finish the task (neural network training)
- add it to the GPU will smallest approximated time

### Time estimation

ETA of current task can be approximated quite well given fixed number of samples and epochs. If that's not the case (e.g. early stopping) it will be harder/way harder and would need some heuristic.

When GPUs are overloaded (say each has `5` tasks in queue), what I would do is:

- Stop process currently on-going on GPU
- Run new process for a few batches of data to make rough estimation how long it might take to finish this task
- Ask it to the estimation of all tasks

Now, this depends on the traffic. If it's big and would interrupt on-going process too often you should simply add new tasks to GPU queue which has the least amount of tasks (some heuristic would be needed here as well, you should have estimated possible amount of requests by now, assuming only 2 GPUs it cannot be huge probably).